# python split all lines in columns, no spaces in lines

Tags: python, split, lines

I have seen many ways to split lines of a text file into columns, but I didn't find the way to do it with lines with no spaces.

My text file looks like:
CABDCBADBCADBC
CBDACBABCABCDA
BCDABCDABABABC
CBADCBACBADBCA

And I would like to split this into columns and then work with each column. So I should get something like:

```
a = [C,C,B,C]  
b = [A,B,C,B]  
c = [B,D,D,A]  
[...]
```

Then I would like to know how many times each letter is in each column.

It looks simple, but I didn't manage to make it and didn't find nothing similar... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is the width of your columns fixed?

Comment: Yes it is fixed the width of my lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the lines are the same length and you're using Python 2 you could use [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import izip

with open('test.txt') as f:
    print [(x, Counter(x)) for x in izip(*(line.strip() for line in f))]
```

Output (partial):

```
[
    (('C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), Counter({'C': 3, 'B': 1})), 
    (('A', 'B', 'C', 'B'), Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 1})), 
    (('B', 'D', 'D', 'A'), Counter({'D': 2, 'A': 1, 'B': 1})),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generator object, that will return each column on calling the next method on it. it assumes that all lines are of the same length. but if they are not so, you can wrap the the appending in a simple try and except block

```
def generateCol(f):
    lines = f.readlines()
    col_count = len(lines[0]) #Assuming all lines are of the same length
    for col in xrange(col_count):
        curr_col = []
        for line in lines:
            curr_col.append(line[col])
        yield curr_col
```

Usage:

```
gen = generateCol(open('fileName', 'r'))
print gen.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want every character to be in separate column then the solution would be given that all lines are same in length

```
st = \
"""CABDCBADBCADBC
CBDACBABCABCDA
BCDABCDABABABC
CBADCBACBADBCA"""

print zip(*st.split("\n"))
```

result:

```
[('C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'D', 'D', 'A'), ('D', 'A', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'D', 'A'), ('D', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'D'), ('D', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'D', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all lines are of the same length:

```
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]  # getting rid of '\n'
    columns = [[line[i] for line in lines] for i in range(len(lines[0]))]

print(columns)  # columns is a list of lists, each list is a column
>> [['C', 'C', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B'], ... , ['C', 'A', 'C', 'A']]
```

Now counting each letter in each column is just a matter of using `count()` or `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

print([Counter(col) for col in columns])
>>  [Counter({'C': 3, 'B': 1}), Counter({'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'A': 1}), ...,
     Counter({'C': 2, 'A': 2})]
```